# Weird x86 function calling convention

Tags: disassembly, x86, calling-conventions, msvc

I have come across some weird function. It's in an x86 LE Windows executable compiled with Visual Studio and linking to v100 runtime.
The function seems to be an `__stdcall` as it ends with a move into `eax` and `ret 0x4`. The first weird thing is it takes one parameter on the stack (the result of `GetCommandLineA`) but right at the start it does `lea eax, [edi+0x8]` without ever writing to `edi`. I figured out it's a custom calling convention and the second parameter is passed in `edi`. It's called from a very big (400 lines when decompiled) `main` function, so I didn't know what exactly is being passed but it seemed like an address on callers stack. I thought it's some array of pointers until I realized it's actually 3 parameters passed as one. The callers stack looks like this:

```
...
|----------|
|  char *  |   >   command line on heap
|          |   <   edi
|----------|
|   int    |   >   argument counter
|----------|
|  char *  |   >   char*[256] pointers to arguments
|----------|
|  char *  |
|----------|
|  char *  |
|----------|
...
```

The function copies the command line to heap, assigns the address to `[edi]`, sets `[edi+0x4]` to `0` and calls `memset([edi+0x8],0,1024)`. Then it goes through the command line and does this:

```
        00401185 8b 4f 04        MOV        ECX,dword ptr [Addr + 0x4]
        00401188 89 74 8f 08     MOV        dword ptr [Addr + ECX*0x4 + 0x8],Heap
        0040118c 01 5f 04        ADD        dword ptr [Addr + 0x4],EBX                   # EBX=1
```

if it finds a new argument.

How can a function operate on it's caller's stack?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What x86 calling convention passes first parameter via ESI?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2673/what-x86-calling-convention-passes-first-parameter-via-esi) - whole-program optimisation on x86 generates a lot of these "custom" calling conventions for the sake of speed.